# Exponent of a Group and a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$.
Now I have to show, that 
$$\text{exp}(G) \space| \space \text{exp}(N)\cdot \text{exp}(G/N)$$ and
$$\text{exp}(G/M) \space| \space \text{exp}(G/N)\cdot \text{exp}(N/M)$$

I dont really know how to start on this one, so I am very grateful for every hint and advice!

Thank you!

Comment: See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_extension_group_divides_product_of_exponents_of_normal_subgroup_and_quotient_group

Comment: @HongyiHuang Thanks! But that doesnt really help me :/

Comment: If I look at the definition of $G\N$ I get that $\text{exp}(G/N)$ $=\text{min}\left{ k\in\mathbb{N} | (gN)^k = g^k N = N \forall g\in G \right}$, which means that $\text{exp}(G/N)=\text{exp}(G)$. Is this correct? It seems a little bit strange